# CSS transitions for Single Page App section contents

Tags: javascript, cordova, handlebars.js

I am developing a single page app using js/handlebars/phonegap. In the beginning the architecture was multiple pages using jquery mobile to do slide or flip effects using the standard data-transition="slide" attribute on  tags. Pretty standard stuff. Since then i have switched over to handlebars and the architecture has become single pages with content loading into a container div.

```
<div data-role="page" id="mealplans">
        <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed">
            <div class="center-wrapper">
                <img src="img/logo.png" width="40" height="40"/>
            </div>
            <div class="accountMenu">
                <a href="home.html" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/menu.png" width="30" height="30"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container" data-role="main">
        </div>
    </div>
```

My page content is injected into the "container" div using append or innerHTML commands.

What i want is to have transitions between content loads where it looks like a slide effect. But since i only have one container that i am changing the inner content of then i am sure i would need something like a second container ?

I have been following this post http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/ but i am not sure how it plays out with my content being loaded in a specific div.

Basically i want to show a slide effect on the content that is loaded in the "container" div.

Can someone help me digest the link above and apply to my architecture.

thanks in advance.

Comment: wrap the current content in a new div, set the div to abs pos and start fading it while you inject in the new content. when if fades out, remove it from the dom.

Comment: What about the new content that has to come in. and what about switching back and forth and doing it gracefully with a dynamic solution ? I know how to fade a div out ... what about switching between content ... fade old content out ... bring in new content and faded it in .

Comment: if you set the inner wrapper to abs pos, you can put it in front of the new content that's a sibling to that inner wrapper. then, when you fade the wrapper/old out, the new is revealed from behind...